# What does the following code return? mssql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I'm digging in somebodies code and I'm not a pro in sql. Could anybody tell me, what the following returns?

```
select DATEADD(day, DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE()) * - 1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: The answer depends on what the date is ;)

Comment: @gvee That just gives an opportunity for someone to post a correct answer every day! ;)

Comment: Off-topic flag is so misused sooo misused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In layman's terms, this returns "Last Saturday". In the case of "today" being a Saturday, it still returns the Saturday before last.

```
-- This will make it very apparent
-- Please note that the DatePart() function is language/settings dependant. So while on one server set up it may return "last Saturday", on others it may return "last Sunday"
select DATEADD(day, DATEPART(weekday, '11/01/2013') * -1, '11/01/2013')
select DATEADD(day, DATEPART(weekday, '11/02/2013') * -1, '11/02/2013')
select DATEADD(day, DATEPART(weekday, '11/03/2013') * -1, '11/03/2013')
select DATEADD(day, DATEPART(weekday, '11/04/2013') * -1, '11/04/2013')
select DATEADD(day, DATEPART(weekday, '11/05/2013') * -1, '11/05/2013')
select DATEADD(day, DATEPART(weekday, '11/06/2013') * -1, '11/06/2013')
select DATEADD(day, DATEPART(weekday, '11/07/2013') * -1, '11/07/2013')
```

Comment: Thank you. One more question, if you don't mind. What does the star do?

Comment: (*) This is multiplication. It multiplies a number by negative one to make the inverse of the number. The inverse is used to "count backwards" towards the last Saturday.

Comment: Thank you! That was a big help!

Comment: Please note that the [`DatePart()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function is language/settings dependant. So while on one server set up it may return "last Saturday", on others it may return "last Sunday".

Comment: gvee, I added this very important note to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE())
```

return you day of week.

- sunday = 1
- monday = 2
- etc...

then :

```
select DATEADD(day, DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE()) * - 1, GETDATE())
```

example for wednesday = 4

Add (4 days * -1 ) to today = today - 4 days